# Probability and the case of People vs Collins (1968)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Could someone explain the intuition here.

If A is the event that at least one couple has the characteristics, why is the event A listed as the intersections of all the Ai's not happening?

By extension I do not see what B represents here either. I understand C is the Probability that exactly one couple has the characteristics.

I would really appreciate your help.

[This is the question I am referring to, it is from Statistics by DeGroot page 71](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHKqH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Look again: $$A=(A_1^\complement\cap A_2^\complement\cap\cdots\cap A_n^\complement)^{\color{red}\complement}$$
so $A$ is (correctly) written as the *opposite* of all couples not having the property, which is just a more manageable rewording of *at least* one copuple has the property.
Now with $C$ representing *exactly* one couple has the property, $B=A\cap C^\complement$ represents the case of  *at least one but not exactly one*, i.e., *at least two*.

Comment: I did notice this but again it confused me. Wouldn't this mean that ALL couples have that property? Seeing as the opposite of all couples not having the property is that ALL have the property?

Answer (score 0):

Event A is atleast one couple has the characteristics is same as from probability of all possibilities substrate when none of couple has characteristics. i.e P(A)=1-$\;{(1-p)}^n$.
Event B is atleast 2 of the couple has characteristics hence from atleast one i.e from event A if we remove exactly one couple ( i.e event C ) has characteristics we get B. 
P(B)=P(A)-P(B).
        = 1-${(1-p)}^n\;-\;np{(1-p)}^{(n-1)}$.